# Атрибут модели в Rails, undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Всем привет, пробую писать на ruby on rails

Есть необходимость раз в день выкачивать данные из удаленной базы. Создал модель

```
 class CrmObject < ActiveRecord::Base
      establish_connection :crm
      self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled #в удаленной таблице есть поле type
      self.table_name = 'objects'
    end
```

Далее в контроллере делаю

```
@objs = CrmObject.limit(1).all
@obj = @objs.first
```

И получаю ошибку на второй строчке: "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:111:in `read_attribute'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:47:in`**temp**36c6163737'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/core.rb:213:in `init_with'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:52:in`instantiate'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/querying.rb:48:in `block in find_by_sql'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/result.rb:55:in`block in each'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/result.rb:55:in `each'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/result.rb:55:in`each'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/querying.rb:48:in `map'
...

Как это исправить?

К слову, я не могу менять таблицу, т.к. она не из моего приложения.

Прилагаю схему таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `objects` (
  `id` int(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `adress_city` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `adress_street` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `adress_house` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `adress_okrug` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Нет',
  `adress_postcode` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `adress_on_site` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `name_eng` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `broker` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `approuve` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `residential` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `floors` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `provider` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `metro1` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `metro2` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_metro1` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `to_metro2` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `to_metro1_metr` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `to_metro2_metr` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `region` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `class` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `vent` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cond` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lift` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lift_quant` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lift_gruz` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lift_gruz_quant` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `park_coeff` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `park_grnd` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `park_ugrnd` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `park_grnd_cost` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `park_ugrnd_cost` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `park_grnd_val` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `park_ugrnd_val` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `obj_info` text NOT NULL,
  `obj_info_site` varchar(8192) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `online` date NOT NULL,
  `c_date` date NOT NULL,
  `p_date` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'Дата следующего звонка',
  `lc_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00' COMMENT 'Дата последнего звонка',
  `owner` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `build_date` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `building_area` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `zone_area` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `zone_contract` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `coords_x` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `coords_y` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `is_exclude` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `geog_region` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tax_house` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fireguard` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `infrastructure` varchar(8192) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `guard` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `management` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `highway` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_change` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `last_sync` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `approuve` (`approuve`),
  KEY `owner` (`owner`),
  KEY `metro1` (`metro1`),
  KEY `metro2` (`metro2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3658 ;
```

Comment: Попробуйте так: @obj = CrmObject.take

Comment: Тоже самое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044043/legacy-table-with-column-named-class-in-rails

```
class CrmObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :crm
  self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
  self.table_name = 'objects_copy'

  class << self
    def instance_method_already_implemented?(method_name)
      return true if method_name == 'class'
      super
    end
  end
end
```